# JPA query compare lists

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

Let's say I have an entity like this:

```
public class Class1 {

private long id;
    ...
private List<OneRandomObject> list;
}
```

is it possible in JPA with criteria query or named query to compare entities by their lists?

something like a named query:

```
select c from Class1 c where c.list=:list
```

queries using criteria api would work fine as well.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this matches your case, but won't this do what you want?

```
    public List<Class1> matchList(List<OneRandomObject> other) {
        // ...
        String jpql = "select c from Class1 c where c.list in (:other)"
        // ...
    }
```

I see what you are asking now. How about something this in Hibernate Criteria API?

```
    Criteria crit = session.createQuery(Class1.class);

    Conjunction junction = Restrictions.conjunction();

    for(OneRandomObject o: matches) {
        junction.add(Restrictions.propertyEq("list", o);
    }

    crit.add(junction);
```

Comment: 1. If you add the parenthesis around :other, you'll get a type mismatch saying you are trying to put an ArrayList in a OneRandomObject.
2. Without the parenthesis it works, but you'll get a row for any element in c.list matching with any element in other. So this won't do if you want to make sure all elements in the list match.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, it's impossible to filter the whole collection as a property.

Maybe you can try to get all Class1 along with `the list` by your conditions, and filter the result as below:

```
for(Class1 c1 : class1List)
{
    List<OneRandomObject> list = c1.getList();
    // compare the list with you param
    // remove if not match
}
```

Comment: Yes i tought that as well,i did not want to take the road of iterating through all the lists,as it can get nasty,it would be easier for me to just change the entities and link them tighter together.The question was more of interest to me to see how i could handle lists comparison in jpa,since they are teorethicaly objects i tought that would be easy.I'll wait to see if someone has any better ideas maybe.In the meantime thank you for your answer.

Comment: This would be the way to go I guess. `CollectionUtils` helps with relieving some of the collection pain. I use `CollectionUtils.subtract(list, otherList).isEmpty()` to compare the collections, for instance.